# Inheriting and map c++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to do multiple inheritance in C++:

```
class Element{
public:
    Element(): common_variable(0) {}
    int common_variable;
};

class Number:public Element, public Setupable{
public:
Number() {}
    vector<Digit> digit_vector;
};
class MultiLed:public Element, public Setupable{
public:
MultiLed() {}
    vector<Led> led_vector;
};
```

The object Element is never instanciated but I use it to avoid code repetition in Multiled and Number.

There is a map that include a Number : `map<string,Number> mNumbers`, and I would like it to be created at the first use:

```
mNumbers["blabla"].digit_vector.push_back(digit);
```

But this doesn't work. The call to the constructors of Element, Setupable and Number is correctly done. But the programs stops at the "push_back" call saying :

```
undefined symbol: _ZN14AcElementD2Ev
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The definition of "Setupable" could be also helpful ...

Comment: Are you compiling with GCC, and is that the exact symbol? It looks almost, but not quite, like the GCC-mangled name for the destructor of a class called `AcElement`. Do you have a class with a name like that, and do you declare a destructor in that class?

Comment: @Jav Do you have a static member D2Ev in Element?

Comment: Encapsulation, ever heard about it? http://bit.ly/i7Y2tL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't post all code, I have to guess the situation in your code. I'll update my answer when you update the question.
Most likely, you have declared a static member in Element, the name is likely to be `D2Ev`, but you forgot to provide a definition for it.

When you define base class, don't forgot to declare virtual destructor.

```
class Element{
public:
    Element():common_variable(0) {
    }
    virtual ~Element(){
    }
    int common_variable;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got two problems here

1. Access restrictions: in `class` all members are private by default
2. Your contructors are not defined, only declared

Patched code:

```
class Element{
public:
    Element(){
        common_variable = 0;
    }
    int common_variable;
};

class Number:public Element, public Setupable{
public:
Number() {}
    vector<Digit> digit_vector;
};
class MultiLed:public Element, public Setupable{
public:
MultiLed() {}
    vector<Led> led_vector;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

digit_vector is private and you are trying to access outside its class.

Answer (score 0):

simply you forget to set public methods and variables

```
class Number:public Element, public Setupable 
{
 public:
    Number(): Element(), Setupable() {}
    vector<Digit> digit_vector;
};
```

by the way, havin a member variable public is not always good idea,
you should provide a method returning the digit_vector

```
//the method is provided in 2 soups, and there are reson for that
//even if you can omitt the "const" version, is better you keep both
const vector<Digit> & getDigits() const { return digit_vector; }
vector<Digit> & getDigits() { return digit_vector; }
```

or if your class have to be just a "data container" make it a struct

```
struct Number:public Element, public Setupable 
{
    //default construsctors of Element and Setupable are still called!
    //if not providing a default constructor, the compiler will create one
    //automatically calling all default constructor (including the vector's
    //one. Also digit_vector is constructed.

    vector<Digit> digit_vector;
};
```

struct is same as class, the only difference is that by default members are all public,
and so you don't have to specifci "public:". A good style is to use only classes (and you must remeber what have to be public or private), and just use structs where you have a data container with almost no bevhaiour/logic.

so writing:

```
class Number:public Element, public Setupable 
{
    //default construsctors of Element and Setupable are still called!
    //if not providing a default constructor, the compiler will create one
    //automatically calling all default constructor (including the vector's
    //one. Also digit_vector is constructed.

 public:
    vector<Digit> digit_vector;
};
```

is valid too. but usually you don't want constructors called implicitly.

Comment: okay, I corrected this little mistake (in fact, I misscopied the code because "public:" was already written).

Comment: I tried the above code and it compiles fine (using empty Led and Digit of course). If there's an error, is not in the code you posted or is in your IDE settings .. to see the code I compiled:
http://pastebin.com/E5YkV7ME

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to implement the destructor ~Element(){}
Now it works...

Sorry everyone for this stupid mistake.

Thx anyway !